# RavenDB MultiMap Index

Tags: ravendb

I am new to RavenDB. I am trying to use a multi map index feature, though I am not sure if it is the best approach to my problem. So I have three documents: Unit, Car, People.

Car document looks like this:

```
{
 Id: "cars/123",
 PersonId: "people/1235",
 UnitId: "units/4321",
 Make: "Toyota",
 Model: "Prius"
}
```

People document looks like this:

```
{
   Id: "people/1235",
   FirstName: "test",
   LastName: "test"
}
```

And unit doc:

```
{
   Id: "units/4321",
   Address: "blah blah"
}
```

This is an abbreviated example, in my real app there are way more fields, so data de-normalization would be my last resort.

I need to create and index that will have all of this three docuemnts joined in one document. Something like this:

```
{
   CarId: "cars/123",
   PersonId: "people/1235",
   UnitId: "units/4321",
   Make: "Toyota",
   Model: "Prius"
   FirstName: "test",
   LastName: "test"
   Address: "blah blah"
}

// same unit different person owns a different car

{
   CarId: "cars/122",
   PersonId: "people/1236",
   UnitId: "units/4321",
   Make: "Toyota",
   Model: "4runner"
   FirstName: "test",
   LastName: "test"
   Address: "blah blah"
}
```

In a relational database I would just use two joins to People and Unit tables by ids 
and my car table would be an aggregate entity.

Here is the index definition that I have:

```
 public class MyMultiIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<JoinedDocument>
 {
    public MyMultiIndex()
    {
        // creating maps
        AddMap<Car>(cars => cars.Select(e => new { e.CarId, e.Make, e.Model, PersonId = e.PersonId, UnitId = e.UnitId, FirstName = (null)string, LastName = (null)string, Address = (nul)string }));
        AddMap<People>(people => people.Select(e => new { CarId = (string)null, Make = (string)null, Model = (string)null, PersonId = e.Id, UnitId = (null)string, FirstName = e.FirstName, LastName = e.LastName, Address = (nul)string }));
        AddMap<Unit>(people => people.Select(e => new { CarId = (string)null, Make = (string)null, Model = (string)null, PersonId = (null)string, UnitId = e.null, FirstName = (nul)string , LastName = (nul)string , Address = e.Address }));

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.CarId
                            into g
                            select new JoinedDocument
                            {
                                CarId = g.Key,
                                PersonId = g.First(e => e.CarId == g.Key).PersonId,
                                UnitId = g.First(e => e.CarId == g.Key).UnitId,
                                Model = g.First(e => e.CarId == g.Key).Model,
                                Make = g.First(e => e.CarId == g.Key).Make,

                                **// this never works. It is like result set does not contain anything with this personId. It looks like AddMap for people document did not work.**

                                FirstName = results.First(e => e.PersonId == g.First(ie => ie.CarId == g.Key).PersonId).FirstName,

                                **// this never works. It is like result set does not contain anything with this personId. It looks like AddMap for people document did not work.**

                                LastName = results.First(e => e.PersonId == g.First(ie => ie.CarId == g.Key).PersonId).LastName,

                                **// this never works. It is like result set does not contain anything with this personId. It looks like AddMap for unit document did not work.**

                                UnitAddress = results.First(e => e.UnitId == g.First(ie => ie.CarId == g.Key).UnitId).LastName,
                           };
        Index(map => map.Model, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(map => map.Make, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(map => map.LastName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(map => map.FirstName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(map => map.Make, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(map => map.UnitAddress, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
 }
```

When RavenDb runs this index I see errors when it is trying to run the Reduce function I have provided. It throws error when I am trying to match a record where person's first name and last name exist, same happens with the unit.

Comment: Cross post with mailing-list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ravendb/Uym2tkvMaH8

Comment: [This post](http://ayende.com/blog/156225/relational-searching-sucks-donrsquo-t-try-to-replicate-it) addresses this question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to fit a document database with an object model that has relationships. This blog may help you:

[Keeping a Domain Model Pure with RavenDB](http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2012/03/keeping-domain-model-pure-with-ravendb.html)

Keep in mind that this isn't the recommended use of RavenDB, but sometimes it's necessary, and this is a good way to handle it.

Comment: So as I understand, denormlization would be the easiest and recommended approach here?

Comment: I think if you want to stay true to RavenDB, then yes.

Comment: -1 this is a terribly brittle solution, the author talks about keeping models pure but relationships have meaning to ignore the meaning of relationships is exactly what leads to all of the crap that falls out when working with ORMs.

Comment: What do you mean by ignoring the meaning of relationships?

Comment: @BobHorn relationships between models inherently have meaning. The decision of List<string> RelatedDocIds vs List<RelatedDoc> is not a persistence decision it is a model design issue. This decision has many implications. The author of that blog claims that what he's doing is some how keeping his models "pure" but that's actually false. He's made his models **very** impure. Instead of designing well defined transactional boundaries between his models he instead created a solution that is entirely dependent upon the persistence mechanism. He created a RavenDB ORM which is an antipattern.

Comment: So what would you suggest in order to keep domain entities having relationships, yet storing them with RavenDB?

Comment: Chris Marisic, I tend to agree with you. In this case the model design is forced by the RavenDB ORM, which is not good. But there is always something that you have to sacrifice using any of the ORMS. Not a perfect world.

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a car with no owner? or an address with no resident? If its false in both cases, I would model the car and unit to be embedded inside a person. So the person becomes your aggregate root and to get to a car or a unit you must go through a person.

Comment: Yes, that was essentially what I had to do.